# Found data of type Ljavax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlAccessType;.FIELD

Tags: java, xml, annotations

I'm facing following issue while doing the Marshalling the XML using the **JAXBContext**

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Cdata.class);
```

Error log:

```
java.lang.annotation.AnnotationTypeMismatchException: 
 Incorrectly typed data found for annotation element public abstract
 javax.xml.bind.annotation.AccessType javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType.value()
 (Found data of type Ljavax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlAccessType;.FIELD)
```

Comment: Could you add `Cdata` class definition?

Comment: package com.snr.jaxb;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;


@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {

  })
@XmlRootElement(name = "cdata")
public class Cdata1
{

Comment: Edit your post. Not in comment